# Eclipse .log file listing errors

Tags: java, eclipse

https://gist.github.com/climbpg/1b04860780f06bc32853741c217e711b

Above is my .log file. There are so many errors, but I believe it is mostly caused by Java heap space.

Comment: Did you try launching Eclipse with the `-clean` option, as in `eclipse.exe -clean` ?

Comment: @Abra I have read something about that somewhere but I wasn't sure how I can do so. Do I need to modify the eclipse.ini file to do that? What commands do I give?

Comment: I presumed you are using a Windows computer. Simply open a command prompt window and enter the path to the `eclipse.exe` file. On my Windows computer that would be: `C:\Users\USER\eclipse\eclipse.exe -clean` You don't have to change anything in file `eclipse.ini` By the way, did you look at the workspace log file?

Comment: @Abra I tried doing so, it gets me to the usual workspace window, but when I select a workspace and launch it, it would load for few seconds, then the entire program would close and nothing happens. Also, yes I have seen the log file, it shows me a long list of errors

Comment: [edit] your question and add the ___relevant___ parts from the workspace log file.

Comment: @Abra I only basically included the first part of the .log file, but as I mentioned I believe this has something to do with the heap size error

Comment: So what are your heap space settings in the `eclipse.ini` file? Mine are set to: `-Xms256m` and `-Xmx1024m`